# OSM, OpenLayers and Google-maps always set to lon/lat (0,0)

Tags: google-maps, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am trying to adapt the following OSM/OpenLayers example that uses Google maps to a project of mine

```
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/google-map.html
```

I built the following page which is pretty straightforward :

```
http://185.8.104.235/testOSM/testOSM.html
```

The problem is that the map is always set to lon/lat (0,0) when the page loads, when I would like to zoom to different coordinates.
IOW, view.setZoom(5) works, while view.setCenter([47, 3]) doesn't...

Any suggestion ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide (a simplified but executable version of) your problematic code in the question, not on a server. As it is, this question will be useless to future readers as soon as you take down your test server.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the center in degrees (because you maybe think coordinates are in EPSG:4326) whereas defaut coordinates in OpenLayers 3 use EPSG:3857 aka Spherical Mercator.

You must make the conversion from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857

In your code,

```
var center = ol.proj.transform(view.getCenter(), 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
```

should be

```
var center = ol.proj.transform(view.getCenter(), 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```

and

```
view.setCenter([47, 3]);
```

should be

```
view.setCenter(ol.proj.transform([47, 3], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I only had to change the second line of my script (view.setCenter([47, 3])) according to your suggestion to make everything run fine, as you can see on the link.